# When is the fork of preload done in gunicorn?

Tags: python, fastapi, gunicorn

I'm trying to understand something that I don't think is in the doc of gunicorn.
For the feature `preload_app` it says `Load application code before the worker processes are forked.` , but when is the process actually forked, and how can gunicorn know when it should fork ?

For instance, if my fastapi code looks like this with a `main.py` file:

```
# some code goes here
...
app = FastAPI(title=x)

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return "ok"
```

and if I start it like so:

```
gunicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --workers 4 --preload
```

At what point will the initial process actually be forked ?
is it before the creation of "app" object ?
is it at the end of the execution of the main.py file ?

Comment: A quick google search yielded e.g. [this explanation](https://www.joelsleppy.com/blog/gunicorn-application-preloading/). Does that answer your question?

Comment: no... it just explains that processes are forked, but not really what is guaranteed to be executed or not before the fork occurs

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It would be easier to answer the question if we knew what result you are after.

Comment: the problem is quite simple, let's say I load a huge file in memory in order to make it available for all my endpoints and all my workers. I want that this data in memory is shared through preload. Where should I load this data in my toy example ? Is it mandatory that this is loaded before "app" is declared ? why or why not?

Comment: When gunicorn loads your app, it `import`s it, and since a Python file is run top to bottom, that will execute any code at root level in that file (or any file it imports). If you however were to load that file in `@app.event("startup")` it would not be shared.

Comment: What you are describing is almost exactly the memory usage example in the article I linked, except that loading a huge file into memory is done by importing numpy and matplotlib